# How can I index into an array using the thread id?

Tags: c++, multithreading

If I want to have a separate object per thread, like a memory allocator (specifically a command pool with Vulkan), I want each thread to access a different member of an array. How can I do this given that `std::thread::thread_id` isn't convertible to the `unsigned int` (which is what it holds in its class)?

```
struct CommandPool {};
CommandPool per_thread_command_pools[8];

CommandBuffer getCommandBuffer()
{
    return per_thread_command_pools[std::this_thread::get_id()].getCommandBuffer();
}
```

I think this is how multi-threading is handled in cases where you spawn a bunch of threads at the start of the program and the worker threads each have their own object. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local might be worth a look

Comment: Beat me to it, @Mat.  So, yes, why not `thread_local CommandPool per_thread_command_pool`?

Comment: Do any other threads need to have access to the `CommandPool`  assigned to `this_thread`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, it's only that one thread. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Zebrafish I'm thinking that you could perhaps create thread classes with a `CommandPool` member. Perhaps [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/Eca8zWxhv)

Comment: Thread I’d is a distraction here. It’s utterly trivial to generate a unique integer value per thread with a global `std::atomic<int>`.

Comment: @Zebrafish Can you tell us a little more about what the setup looks like?

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, but when calling a function how do you (in the function) access thread local variables if you don't know the thread id, even if you generate it. Do you mean pass it in as an argument?

Comment: @TedLyngmo What I've trying to do is have background threads pick up jobs placed onto a queue. When the job is done by an individual thread it can do things like push commands into a Vulkan command buffer, which will have its own pool, that can should only be accessed by one particular thread.  So when a job is picked up and it calls for example the render function, from that render it needs to access the pool corresponding with that thread_id. I thought to use an array of them, and the thread_id as the index. Some people use a map.

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't it work to put a `CommandPool` in each thread class that does the work in that case? Each instance of the class will have its own `CommandPool` and then there's no need for lookups or even `thread_local`s.

Comment: `std::atomic<int> id_gen = 0;` as a global, then in each thread `int my_id = id_gen++;`.

Comment: @PeteBecker The thing is how can I get the thread id when calling a function? The thread, let's say it even has a this pointer, if it calls graphics::render() how do I then get the thread id if that happens? At least with std::thread_id it's known everywhere.

Comment: @Zebrafish Why do you need the thread id? Why do you want to lookup the `CommandPool` in a container that is shared with other threads? I still don't understand why you don't create the `CommandPool` as part of creating the thread. Don't you have other data that is unique to each thread?

Comment: @Zebrafish To show you what I mean, I made [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/W1MYKd1sa). No `thread_local` or thread id needed. Wouldn't that work?

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, use `thread_local` variables.

Less ideally, give each thread its array index via a lambda capture or equivalent.

Even less ideally, if the data structure *must* be indexed by `std::thread::id`, why not use a `std::map<std::thread::id, SomeData>`?

Comment: "Less ideally, give each thread its array index via a lambda capture or equivalent." Yes, but how do I even get the thread index in the first place? the only way I can get the thread id is through get_id(), and that I can't index with that now convert it to an indexable type.

Comment: @Zebrafish, A `thread_local` is just a hash table under the covers. If there's some reason why you can't use `thread_local`, then why not make your own hash table (a.k.a., "[`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)?") I haven't tried it myself, but the [`thread_id`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id) class appears to have the necessary [hash support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id/hash).

Comment: @SolomonSlow Using an `unordered_map` would work - but then you'd need a `mutex` to lock the map when updating it. Otherwise two threads could require their `CommandPool` at the same time and cause two simultaneous inserts in the map.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Re, "you'd need a mutex" Yes, but I don't see that as a particularly difficult problem to overcome.

Comment: @SolomonSlow No, it's not difficult at all, but it seems like a wasteful way to get access to thread local data.

Comment: @Zebrafish You do not _get_ the thread index, you _set_ it. When each thread should have its data structure of some sort, the assumption is that you know how many threads there will be. That gives you a way to generate an index for each thread, e.g. from a simple counter. Or maybe not an index, but an iterator, a direct reference to the thread’s data structure or whichever other equivalent one may think of. If threads can spawn other threads and there is no central place where they start, you can use e.g. an atomic counter to index the threads. Anyway, no matter what, try `thread_local` first.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek I can give each thread its own id via a counter, but inside a function how is the thread id known?

Comment: @Zebrafish I already wrote that in the answer. Pass it in a lambda capture. Or as a member of a functor instance (which is essentially the same thing).

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek I mean in calling other functions. thread_id has the functionality that you can call any function and you know which thread it is. The only I can think of to replicate this is to pass the thread id as a function argument, or put it into the class where calling the function will have it in the this pointer. I'm talking about calling other functions.

Comment: @Zebrafish Then `thread_local` is the way to go. (Not that the manual map wouldn’t work too, but it requires a lot of wheel reinventing (locking, cleanup of finished threads etc.). `thread_local` solves all that.)

Comment: @Zebrafish ... and still, why not just create an instance of `CommandPool` in the started thread? I've tried to get you to explain the reason _why_ you need it to be in a container or `thread_local`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Even if the command pool is in the thread object itself, when it picks up a job to call the render function, then in the render function, where it then has to use that particular command pool, there is no concept of which thread called it. I might just pass the threads in as argument.

Comment: _" there is no concept of which thread called it"_ - No, that sounds correct and matches what I did in my [example](https://godbolt.org/z/W1MYKd1sa). What am I missing?